# How to send multiple data to a service?

Tags: apex, callout

I am going through the apex integration module. I can see how we can send one record to a service. But what if we want to send multiple records to the service?

```
Http http = new Http();
HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
request.setEndpoint('https://th-apex-http-callout.herokuapp.com/animals');
request.setMethod('POST');
request.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json;charset=UTF-8');
// Set the body as a JSON object
request.setBody('{"name":"mighty moose"}');
HttpResponse response = http.send(request);
// Parse the JSON response
if(response.getStatusCode() != 201) {
    System.debug('The status code returned was not expected: ' + response.getStatusCode() + ' ' + response.getStatus());
} else {
    System.debug(response.getBody());
}
```

The above is the code in the trailhead to put one record in the service? What if I want to put more than one record?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the service supports it, you can send multiple values as an array, in JSON defined as `[]`. For example:

```
req.setBody('[{"name":"moose"},{"name":"bear"},{"name":"cat"}]');
```

Some resources use a more "XML-looking" style:

```
req.setBody('{"animals":[{"name:"moose"},{"name":"bear"},{"name":"cat"}]}');
```

If you were writing code in Apex with [RestResource](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_annotation_rest_resource.htm), there would be a top-level "request" object as well:

```
req.setBody('{"request":{"animals":[{"name:"moose"},{"name":"bear"},{"name":"cat"}]}}');
```

However, the Heroku app, above, doesn't support such a syntax. If a resource doesn't support multiple records, there's no way to force it to do so. You could write your own app on Heroku for free and build such an app yourself.

In any event, most apps have online documentation that tell you what kind of JSON they support. You must read the documentation when possible to see what options are supported.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think the POST method implementation at the [trailhead end point](https://th-apex-http-callout.herokuapp.com/animals) supports multiple record insert/ update. If you were to implement a custom apex REST implementation, you can define the the JSON to handle multiple record processing and write the corresponding apex code.

If you want understand how to insert/ update multiple records in a single REST apex, refer to the [composite API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_composite_sobjects_collections.htm) sobject collections.

Comment: Hi, could we perhaps use a JSON String that the POST method would deserialize into multiple records and then perform a DML insert operation?

Comment: @DevelBase2 If the TH endpoint has the corresponding logic implemented already, then yes. However, I don't think its been implemented on this sample end point.

Comment: I did not find anything useful in the link you provided. If there is a tutorial or a blog please suggest. I am looking for the syntax to write the code.

Comment: You can google out the tutorials & blogs. The link I've provided is the official SF developer guide link which has more links and documentation (along with sample payloads) for all that you would need such as [this](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_composite_sobjects_collections_create.htm), [this](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/dome_composite_sobject_tree_flat.htm) etc.